# setting the value of exceeded the quota

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a problem in my vanilla Javascript.

```
localStorage.setItem('article', JSON.stringify(payload));
```

The value of payload is a data of Image and first there is no problem.
But after updating several times, the issue is happened.

Comment: So what is the actual question? ... The max size is generally between 5-10Mb, but can be customized by the user, so there is no guaranteed size.

Comment: Sounds good.
I want to know about how to increase the limit of localstorage.